# Is there a better way to access an object method that has $ character in the name?

Tags: php, oop

I'm parsing an youtube search results with `json_encode` and there is some methods with $ character in the name:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$t] => tag:youtube.com,2008:video:uJQLD6izDkY
        )

    [media$group] => stdClass Object
        (
            [media$description] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => Senador Renan Calheiros fala de situações em que não considera possível abolir o voto secreto no Parlamento. Fonte: TV Senado.
                    [type] => plain
                )
        )
)
```

Currently i'm accessing this methods storing the name in a variable, like this: `$method = '$t'; $obj->id->$method`. Is there a better way to parse or access this methods?

Comment: What's the youtube call you are using, the $ in the name isn't something ordinary.

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=UCdiKR88xD1GO7P3OgJWMGaw&v2&alt=json

Comment: @MarcosLopes: Where's the `$` in that XML? I can't find one.

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be a json output. I fixed the link. Take a look at `feed->id->$t`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [curly bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
echo $obj->id->{'$t'};
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain / suggest improvements? Maybe I could learn something new, too :)